# Can calls to a module or class be intercepted in node.js/Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, dynamic, ecmascript-harmony

In PHP every class contains a "magic" __call function. Using this one can dynamically intercept all calls to a class. For example using

```
class TestClass {

    public function __call($functionname, $arguments) {

        .. functionname called 

    }

}
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call

Is something similar possible in JavaScript/Node.js? Either on a module (loaded by require) or for classes?

**Update:**
Thank you for all who commented. This does not seem to be possible in pure JavaScript. At least currently.

- As  bfavaretto pointed out, this can be done using enabling harmony proxies in Node.js. See [Enable Harmony Proxies in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665892/enable-harmony-proxies-in-nodejs).
- This question seems to be a duplicate of [Get notification when javascript object is invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519264/get-notification-when-javascript-object-is-invoked?lq=1).
- Possibly related: `__noSuchMethod__` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/noSuchMethod), which is marked nonstandard.

Comment: You'll have to wait for the next version of ECMAScript to have that.

Comment: @user2692274 he is referring to `class` and `public` I believe

Comment: @pllee No, I'm referring to [direct proxies](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:direct_proxies)

Comment: @bfavaretto that is interesting stuff and looks like nicer syntax but intercepting methods can be done all versions on ECMAScript.

Comment: @pllee: Yes. Ideally I was hoping to replicate the above php code, and intercept the function names of _all_ calls to some class/module.

Comment: @user2692274 yes that can be done.  The answer below can be applied to  classes and modules.

Comment: @pllee How can you reproduce `__call` in current js? It's supposed to intercept calls to `someInstance.nonExistingMethod()`.

Comment: @bfavaretto I've never heard of `__call` until now and maybe I am misunderstanding it but you could intercept all methods on an instance.  The intercepting method would call `__call` and then the method it just intercepted by doing `return oldMethod.apply(this, arguments)`

Comment: @pllee You're talking about intercepting/overloading existing methods, but `__call` allows you to intercept calls to non-existing methods (see [docs](http://br2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call)). You can't do that in js, `var o = {}; o.foo()` throws an error. In PHP, you can intercept such a call with the magic `__call` method.

Comment: @user2692274 I didn't realize you were asking about Node specifically! You can enable that feature in Node, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665892/enable-harmony-proxies-in-nodejs

Comment: @bfavaretto You are right I thought `all calls to a class` meant all method calls. The php docs clear it up.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this, though it's per-function:

```
// original module
var module = {
   myFunc: function(){ /* ... */ }
}

// "spying" code

var originalFunction = module.myFunc;

module.myFunc = function(){
    // DO SPY STUFF HERE

    return originalFunction.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9eu45/

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I was not aware of this functionality. Unfortunately, it is not quite was I am looking for. This might be useful later though!