# Object.defineProperty on any property

Tags: node.js, properties

I would like to be able to make a dynamic objet in nodejs, which when a poperty is accessed, a function is called with the property name. As an example is far more explicit than a text:

```
// what I am seeking
obj.get = function(name) {
   return "Hello, "+ name
}
console.log(obj.foo); // Excpected : Hello, foo
console.log(obj.bar); // Excpected : Hello, bar
```

**EDIT:**

**I know there is Proxy, but they don't exist in node.js. How to do that in nodejs?**

Comment: Without the ES6 proxy feature, there's really no good way to do this. The language simply doesn't have support for such a thing. *edit* you can always invoke Node with `--harmony_proxies true` ...

Comment: @Pointy maybe, but please reopen since it is no more a duplicate.

Comment: It is a duplicate - whether it's in the browser or Node it's the same issue. Check out the `--harmony_proxies` V8 option for Node.

Comment: OK, thanks but it isn't the same duplicate then : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665892/enable-harmony-proxies-in-nodejs

Comment: Ha I was just about to link that question here :) I'll add a comment to the other one - I think it's a good question with well written answers so it works as a focal point for this topic.